# How to hang a shelf in an invisible manner?

Tags: shelving, hanging

I recently decided to start building my own furniture whenever I could.

To start small, I decided to go with a design’ish shelf that right now looks like that:

[image: my shelf]

I’d obviously like to hang it on the wall but also to do it without visible shelf brackets. I have no idea what technique to use there. The shelf will ultimately carry books and while it is probably sturdy enough to do so, I understand that the wall fixation system is at least as important.

The shelf has an overall width x height of 30’’ x 30’’ and I do have metallic studs in the wall I want to hang it to.

What fixation system can I use in that situation?

Comment: Are the joints of that "shelf" glued together, or are they only held together by  the little brass ell brackets?

Comment: @Tester101 There are small wood pieces (like Ikea furniture has) at each junction and I glued those. It would not seem enough to have just the brass ell brackets I think.

Answer (score 2):

You should look for **Floating** or **Blind** shelf brackets.

You may actually need thicker supports on the tops or bottoms of your shelves to get the right support from these brackets, but this will give the appearance of "floating" that you're looking for

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your shelf won't come apart under the weight of itself and books, you have several options.

1) Your shelf looks wider than standard 24" distance between studs, so you can mark location of the studs behind your shelf at the height where an UPPER horizontal shelf part crosses the stud. Do this near to the left end of the leftmost horizontal & the right end of the rightmost, and *** MARK ON THE WALL AND SHELF BOTH ***. Then buy "lag bolts" with a diameter of half the shelf part thickness (prolly 3/4" so half is 3/8"). But the longest you can find. Drill & screw pointy end into the wall& stud; make sure bolt is straight & level into the wall. Drill same-size (3/8") hole in back edge of your shelf, as deep as the bolt part sticking out the wall. Slide shelf unit over bolts into drilled holes until shelf is tight against wall. The threads on the bolt will grip the insides of the holes & won't slide off except maybe in an earthquake.  Done.

2) if really heavy books, or lots, are on shelf, do same as 1) except don't drill into shelf - instead rest shelf on the bolts (paint bolts black if you like). This isn't as invisible but almost, and is MUCH stronger. OR use more than 2 lag bolts - up to every 4 inches if you want it bombproof.

3) Buy brackets the other poster suggested, but for your shelf you'll need 2 so the other box-area of your shelf doesn't twist itself & break off under weight.

Comment: Sorry, my studs are 24" apart, but many are 16" apart. Just locate them and proceed.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.